# Insert into temporary table an iterate an ID column

Tags: t-sql, sap-ase

I have a select statement that inserts data into a `#temptabl`e, it looks like this:

`select null as ID, Name, AnotherId, date into #TempTable from Table`.

The resulting `#temptable` looks like this:

```
|  Id  |  Name  |  AnotherId  |     Datetime      |
---------------------------------------------------
| null | Login  |    10       |2016-01-01 15:00:00|
| null | Command|    10       |2016-01-01 15:00:01|
| null | Login  |    20       |2016-01-01 15:01:00|
| null | Command|    10       |2016-01-01 15:01:00|
| null | Logout |    10       |2016-01-01 15:01:01|
| null | Command|    20       |2016-01-01 15:01:02|
| null | Logout |    20       |2016-01-01 15:02:00|
```

I would like to put in the Id column a unique ID but with some conditions as:

- When there is a Login assign a unique Id (eg for the 1st Login give Id = 1)
- Then for the next Login have Id = 2
- For the Commands between a Login and a Logout that have the same AnotherId then put the corresponding Id (eg for AnotherId = 10 I should have all the rows that have AnotherId = 10 -> Id = 1)

How should I proceed? Any help appreciated.

Edit: The results I want:

```
|  Id  |  Name  |  AnotherId  |     Datetime      |
| 1    | Login  |    10       |2016-01-01 15:00:00|
| 1    | Command|    10       |2016-01-01 15:00:01|
| 2    | Login  |    20       |2016-01-01 15:01:00|
| 1    | Command|    10       |2016-01-01 15:01:00|
| 1    | Logout |    10       |2016-01-01 15:01:00|
| 2    | Command|    20       |2016-01-01 15:01:02|
| 2    | Logout |    20       |2016-01-01 15:02:00
```

Comment: You should edit the question and show the results you want.  The third condition is hard to express.

Comment: Edited the result.

Comment: My Answer will help you..

Comment: What purpose does the `Id` column serve?  Why not use `AnotherId` instead?  The only different is `Id` is 1 based, while `AnotherId` could start at any value.  But does that matter?  If both ids contain meaningless [surrogate values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) what do you gain from calculating this?

Comment: @destination-data because the AnotherId is reusable and is possible to have two sessions  (Login ... Logout) with the same AnotherId but different timestamp. AnotherId is a session id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want `login`s to have incremental ids, with all rows in-between having the same id.

Another way of expressing this is that the `id` is the number of `login`s on or before a given row.

In SQL Server 2012+, you can do this using ANSI standard cumulative sum functionality:

```
select sum(case when name = 'login' then 1 else 0 end) over
           (partition by anotherId order by datetime) as ID,
       Name, AnotherId, date
into #TempTable
from Table;
```

In earlier versions of SQL Server you can do this using `outer apply`.

EDIT:

The above (although useful) was not a complete understanding of the question.  Instead:

```
select (case when name = 'login' then ID
             else max(ID) over (partition by AnotherId order by DateTime)
        end) as Id,
       Name, AnotherId, date
into #TempTable
from (select sum(case when name = 'login' then 1 else 0 end) over
                 (order by datetime) as ID,
             Name, AnotherId, date
      from Table
     ) t;
```

Comment: I put the result I wanted to have. But you understood what I wanted to say. I will try the solution and come back to rate.